# Сохранение данных при повороте экрана

Tags: android

Понимаю, что инфы по этому вопросу немало, но тут никак не могу заставить код корректно работать. 
Подгружаю данные порциями с сервера, вывожу их списком. при прокрутке вниз подгружаются новые порции данных. Данные подгружаю в AsyncTask.
Вот пример кода:

```
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            int lastScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

            if ((lastScreen) == totalItemCount) {
                if ((from + number) <= totalItemCount) {
                    from = totalItemCount;

                    mt = (MyTask) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
                    if ( mt == null ){
                          mt = new MyTask();
                          mt.execute();
                    }

                    mt.link(this);

                }
            }
        }

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}
    });
```

Поворачиваю эмулятор - белый экран. В чем косяк?

Comment: "прокрути" пальцем этот белый экран, чет появится? я думаю косяк в том что код стоит не там где надо, надо в онРезьюм для получения "старого" потока

Comment: а можно на коде показать как это выглядеть будет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть Вам поможет эта статья [asynctask-rotate-display](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/154-urok-91-asynctask-povorot-ekrana.html).